# React Native Modal isVisible={false} still shows

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I keep running into this issue and its infuriating since there's (to me) absolutely no reason why this should be happening. React Native Modals have a `isVisible` prop to be set to a Boolean, false means the modal is not shown, true means it is. Except every time I do it, false means true and true means true. In my code, I quite literally do not have the word `true` once, yet the modal persists. I tried hard coding it to look like this...

```
 <Modal
        isVisible={false}
        onBackdropPress={() => setShowResetModal(false)}
        hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={0
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        animationIn="zoomIn"
        animationOut="zoomOut"
>
```

And STILL it shows. Impossible to remove it. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Reload the application, what happens then? If the problem persists with hardcoded `false` visibility, then there is something wrong in your code that you have not shared yet.

Comment: have you tried changing to the core modal? I suspect you are using react-native-modal from the props, check if the core modal works or not first.

Comment: Depending on the modal you are using ```visible``` instead of ```isVisible``` https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#visible

Comment: I'm just having the same issue... How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do these changes :

1. You need to add conditional render for modal:

```
{isVisibleModal && <YourModalComponent />}
```

2. Also to provide value 'isVisibleModal' inside Component

```
// YOUR COMPONENT INVOKED IN OTHER COMPONENT
{isVisibleModal && <YourModalComponent isVisibleModal={isVisibleModal} />}

// YOUR SEPARATED COMPONENT
const YourModalComponent = (isVisibleModal, setModalVisible) => {
  return (
    <Modal
        isVisible={isVisibleModal}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        setModalVisible(!isVisibleModal);
      }}>
    >
         <Text>SOME</Text>
    </Modal>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this may not the be the best way to do this but here is what works for me:

```
{isDropdownVisible ? (
        <DropdownMenu
          isVisible={isDropdownVisible}
          onClose={() => setIsDropdownVisible(false)}
          options={dropdownOptions}
        />
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
```